# gmaps4rails v2 bounds and zooming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

`Gmaps.store.handler.getMap().zoomTo(10)` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<pi> has no method 'zoomTo'`

Directly above that, I call Gmaps.store.handler.map.centerOn, with a lat and lng, and it centers properly, so I'm inclined to believe that the handler is right.  I call handler with

```
Gmaps.store = {} #handler, markers, userPin, eventPin
jQuery ->
  Gmaps.store.handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'    
  Gmaps.store.handler.buildMap { internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
    Gmaps.store.markers = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarkers( $('#map').data('events'), 
      draggable: false
      flat: false
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    )

    google.maps.event.addListener Gmaps.store.handler.getMap(), 'click', (event) ->
    addEventMarker event.latLng if $('#createEventWindow').is(':visible')
```

Also, when calling `Gmaps.store.handler.bounds`, I'm getting 180 and 1.  Shouldn't I be able to call `.getNorthEast()` on the bounds as well?  Console tells me there is no such function.  Here's a pic of the beast...

[image: map showing San Diego, bounds are botched]

**Update**

```
updateSearchLocation = ->
  if $('#collapseOne input#location').val()
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
    address = $('#collapseOne input#location').val()
    geocoder.geocode address: address, (results, status) ->
      if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
        latLng = results[0].geometry.location
        Gmaps.store.handler.map.centerOn
          lat: latLng.lat()
          lng: latLng.lng()
        Gmaps.store.handler.getMap().setZoom(10)
        console.log Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.getServiceObject().getNorthEast()
        $('#collapseOne input#ne').val Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.getServiceObject().getNorthEast()
        $('#collapseOne input#sw').val Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.getServiceObject().getSouthWest()
      else
        throw status + ' for ' + address
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google method to set zoom is `setZoom`, so:

```
handler.getMap().setZoom(10)
```

For bounds, a custom object is stored here:

```
handler.bounds
```

like all custom objects like `handler.map` or the markers, if you need to access the google object, you can use `getServiceObject()`

```
handler.bounds.getServiceObject()
handler.map.getServiceObject() # same as handler.getMap()
markers[0].getServiceObject()
...
```

Comment: `.setZoom` was the ticket.  I was trying that before, but I think I was trying just `handler`, or `handler.map`.  Then the `zoomTo()` threw me for a loop.  As for the bounds, I updated my question to show exactly how I'm calling bounds now.  I realize how `getServiceObject()` works, as you can kind of see the object in the console there.  I'm still having the issue where my bounds are showing as `-1, -180` and `1, 180`.  The handler is showing everything else properly, so I don't think the issue is there.  Any ideas?

Comment: `handler.bounds.getServiceObject().getNorthEast().lat()`, `handler.bounds.getServiceObject().getNorthEast().lng()`

Comment: The form is being updated with the bounds... the bounds are just wrong.  `.lat()` gets me a -1, and `.lng()` gets me a -180.  Is it maybe not talking to the map properly?  Did google pull some voodoo stuff, and botch the bounds?